# Compilation errors of a simple C++ project in VS 2012.RC 4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I had a program I could run before upgrading to VS 2012.3 and VS 2012.rc4 (VS ultimate 2012 version 11.0.60930.00 update 4 RC). But It shows some strange errors in some include files after upgrade. Specially, the problem is about the "windows.h" header file. I cannot even compile a simple program, as below. I have also changed the order of include files, but the errors remain. I hope you can help me.

**EDIT:**
When I change the platform toolset from v11 to v10, the errors disappear and I can compile them correctly.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Errors:**

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\rpcndr.h(48): error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\rpcndr.h(48): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(116): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'OLECHAR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(116): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(118): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(118): error C2373: 'OLECHAR' : redefinition; different type modifiers
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(114) : see declaration of 'OLECHAR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(118): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(423): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'BYTE_BLOB'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(423): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(431): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(431): error C2371: 'WORD_BLOB' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(429) : see declaration of 'WORD_BLOB'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(431): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(439): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(439): error C2371: 'DWORD_BLOB' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(437) : see declaration of 'DWORD_BLOB'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(439): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(448): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(448): error C2371: 'FLAGGED_BYTE_BLOB' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(446) : see declaration of 'FLAGGED_BYTE_BLOB'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(448): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(457): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(457): error C2371: 'FLAGGED_WORD_BLOB' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(455) : see declaration of 'FLAGGED_WORD_BLOB'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(457): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(405): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(405): error C2371: 'userCLIPFORMAT' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(403) : see declaration of 'userCLIPFORMAT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(405): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(430): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(430): error C2371: 'userHGLOBAL' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(428) : see declaration of 'userHGLOBAL'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(430): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(517): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(517): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(517): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(519): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(519): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(519): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(521): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(521): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(521): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(523): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(523): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(523): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(525): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(525): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(525): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(527): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(527): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(527): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(529): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(529): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(529): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(531): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(531): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(531): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(533): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(533): error C2371: 'RemotableHandle' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(515) : see declaration of 'RemotableHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(533): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(611): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(611): error C2371: 'userHBITMAP' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(494) : see declaration of 'userHBITMAP'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(611): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(613): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(613): error C2371: 'userHPALETTE' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(505) : see declaration of 'userHPALETTE'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(613): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(615): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(615): error C2371: 'userHENHMETAFILE' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(471) : see declaration of 'userHENHMETAFILE'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(615): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(617): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(617): error C2371: 'userHMETAFILE' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(441) : see declaration of 'userHMETAFILE'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(617): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(619): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(619): error C2371: 'userHMETAFILEPICT' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(460) : see declaration of 'userHMETAFILEPICT'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(619): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(733): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(733): error C2371: 'FLAGGED_WORD_BLOB' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\wtypesbase.h(455) : see declaration of 'FLAGGED_WORD_BLOB'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(733): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(941): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pFileExt'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(941): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(942): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pMimeType'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(942): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(943): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pProgId'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(943): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(944): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pFileName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(944): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(947): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pPackageName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\wtypes.h(947): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(140): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__RPC__deref_out'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(309): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__RPC__deref_out'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(431): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(431): error C2371: 'IClassFactory' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(59) : see declaration of 'IClassFactory'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(431): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(524): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(524): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'IClassFactory'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(524): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(526): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(537): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(537): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'IClassFactory'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(537): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(538): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(575): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(575): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'IClassFactory'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(575): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(577): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(585): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(585): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'IClassFactory'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(585): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(586): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1376): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1376): error C2371: 'IMultiQI' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(94) : see declaration of 'IMultiQI'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1376): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1694): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1694): error C2371: 'IEnumUnknown' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(115) : see declaration of 'IEnumUnknown'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1694): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1805): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1805): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'IEnumUnknown'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1805): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1808): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1828): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1828): error C2371: 'IEnumString' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(122) : see declaration of 'IEnumString'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1828): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1937): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1937): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'IEnumString'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1937): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(1940): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2061): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2061): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ISequentialStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2061): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2064): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2075): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2075): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ISequentialStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2075): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2078): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2098): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2098): error C2371: 'IStream' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(136) : see declaration of 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2098): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2120): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pwcsName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2120): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2361): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2361): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2361): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2364): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2375): error C2065: '__RPC__in' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2375): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'IStream'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2375): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(2379): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(3896): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__RPC__deref_out_opt'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(3914): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__RPC__in_opt'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(4072): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__RPC__deref_out_opt'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(4495): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(4495): error C2371: 'ISurrogate' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(234) : see declaration of 'ISurrogate'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(4495): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(5981): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__RPC__out_ecount_part'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\objidlbase.h(5981): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you by any chance accidentally modified any of the windows kits header files?

Comment: no, absolutely not. I can send the source code of them to check, If you you want.

Comment: I'm guessing that the precompiler headers are confusing the compiler. Try removing any `*.pch` file from your proyect directories. You could even try disably the _precompiled headers_ option alltogether.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In fact, I have disabled the precompiled header files, but as you said, one of the project files (called *.sdf) was the problem. I deleted it, and the problem solved.