# "Triangle" with VS2012?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

There is a triangular mesh generator (Shewchuk, CMU), ["Triangle"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html), that are recommended by people due to its lightweight. It is written in C. However I cannot use it in my VS2012 C++ project. I am compiling it using x64 platform. I am on Windows 7 64-bit.

Basically, I compile the triangle.c as the makefile described. So, a triangle.o is generated. I then

1. added triangle.o as additional dependencies in my solution,
2. added triangle.c and triangle.h in my project .
3. changed triangle.c in C/C++ precompiled header option, to "not using precompiled header"

Then I got tons of errors like this:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(430): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(430): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(497): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(497): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(498): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(498): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(2517): warning C4391: 'SHORT _InterlockedIncrement16(volatile SHORT *)' : incorrect return type for intrinsic function, expected 'short'
```

I am just wondering, is there anyway to make the triangular mesh generator work with VS2012 C++ project? If so, what is the right way to set it up on VS2012 C++ x64?

Comment: You will need to [set FP precision](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.pc.html) although that's not related to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this: [Compilation errors of a simple C++ project in VS 2012.RC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342936/compilation-errors-of-a-simple-c-project-in-vs-2012-rc-4)
disable pre-compiled headers, and delete the pch file from the intermediate directory.

This initially didn't work for me, so I tried moving #include  at the top of the file, before all other includes, and this worked for me.